# TypeScript: Incorrect type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Stumbled upon an incorrect type inference. Perhaps, when checking the type, the depth of traversal of complex structures is limited?

TypeScript version: 4.1.5

```
type ZERO = 0
type Next<T> = T extends ZERO ? {v: ZERO} : (T extends {v: infer U} ? {v: Next<U>} : never)

type ONE = Next<ZERO>
type TWO = Next<ONE>
type THREE = Next<TWO>
type FOUR = Next<THREE>
type FIVE = Next<FOUR>
type SIX = Next<FIVE>
type SEVEN = Next<SIX>
type EIGHT = Next<SEVEN>
type NINE = Next<EIGHT>
type TEN = Next<NINE>

type TEq<T, P> = T extends P ? (P extends T ? true : never) : never

let v1:TEq<TWO, TWO> = true // correct: types is equal
let v2:TEq<TWO, THREE> = true // correct: type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'
let v3:TEq<SIX, EIGHT> = true // error: why type of v3 inferred as true?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWgogJQPJQLxQAwFgBQpJQByEAHsADwAqAfGlJVKcBAHYAmAzrIigPxQBvAG4AubsgC%20UMQAoGTVp0GioASxYAzCACcoAVSn9hY4mXJ7qUsSwhCdASly580JITh1TFeMmrPw0JQA6ijoXuRucH54AfQAEghwHmFMVCHRLlAAYkh6CJ6plAlJGbFZAJIAaslEqTl5pQQAyuUAGgVmFdWN0E1w1YQdFC2tPVBw5QDicQwpZn0DY4Tl7kPkE9M0-gSUcINzFMvu0duBcACOVAA0UAAKtOjyZIpct1D8Mm8K7FwM-MDaACu0Gstgc0igNjs2icOAANhBgFAhABGES7S7BJA3LEPKAA4FQAD0RKgAGMAPbabQQMnAMQuLiqLgQc6AgCGcNwCKRQgATOiLmlsfFElE6AToCTyVSaXSGbEAOQAIwpFIR7JYirUXBYFKR7I4HFUAHMWOzlQj8RT8UqoTpFdzEciAMyCy4jG4bGZ4yXE0k6bRUsQAdwAFiBbQQKRpXWpNIGIGwoIb8UCILwgA)

Comment: Interesting. If you write it literally, it returns false https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWgogJQPJQLxQAwFgBQvSRQIQDOArgDbBpQDeuUjUAbgFx0NNdsc5f9Me9PgNGMhnMVJbth0+YPbxkAbkkL+AXzUiNUberEHdWnV2OaoEAB7AIAOwAmJXt1mHFr+RJMKfegX8AsSDg6VCwvyVEJDNIqWN40w89RIC06QzkkwsoAH4oYAAnMmh2ADMAQwoSCFxcIA

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDACN-BGvI8&feature=youtu.be&t=22m59s) you can find Microsoft build talk.

> [This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35533#issuecomment-574719956) explains design limitation
>
> it's a recursion guard to prevent literally infinite computation. If S needs to compare itself to S<S> to determine assignability, and then S<S> needs to compare itself to S<S<S>>, then S<S<S>> needs to compare itself to S<S<S<S>>>, then S<S<S<S>>> needs to compare itself to S<S<S<S<S>>>>, at that point the checking stops and it's assumed that the answer is "yes". This case actually does come up in practice quite a bit; if your model is dependent on this checking going arbitrarily deep, then effectively you're asking for the compiler to sometimes freeze forever checking S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> against S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (which in turn will check S<SS<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S<S>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.