# TypeScript: Incorrect Type Inference for Property with Conditional Type in Abstract Class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-conditional-types

I have a generic abstract class which has a property with a conditional type.

```js
interface Catalogue<T extends Item> {
    findById(id: T["id"]): T | undefined;
    // ...
}

type CatalogueOrConfigManager<T extends Item | Config> = T extends Item ? Catalogue<T> : T extends Config ? ConfigManager<T> : never;

abstract class BaseStore<T extends Item | Config> {
    protected hotStore: CatalogueOrConfigManager<T>;
    // ...
}
```

when I extend abstract class and try to use the property with conditional type typescript is not inferring its type correctly.

```js
class HotCatalogue<T extends Item> extends BaseStore<T> {
    findById(id): Promise<T | undefined> {
        const doc = this.hotStore.findById(id);
        return doc; // Type 'Item | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.
    }
}
```

In the **`HotCatalogue`** class that extends **`BaseStore`**, TypeScript incorrectly infers return the type of `this.hotStore.findById` as **`Item | undefined`** instead of **`T | undefined`**. As a result, I get a type error when returning the **`doc`** variable.

I tried using the conditional type directly on the property instead of creating a type for it.

```js
abstract class BaseStore<T extends Item | Config> {
    protected hotStore: T extends Item ? Catalogue<T> : T extends Config ? ConfigManager<T> : never;
    // ...
}
```

it didn't work.

I am not sure but maybe it's happening because of limitation described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66452775/5758826) answer. If so, I would appreciate if anyone can explain how it is relating to my issue. What can I do to fix it, or avoid this from happening?